# How to fix signature key?

Tags: docker, signature, kubernetes

I have tried with sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade.
And i get this error with kubernetes error:
I have tried with these following commands below:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But it hasn't worked!
How can i fix this?
Is it that i must get the key somehow?

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                     
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease [115 kB]                                                                                                
Ign:8 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                 
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                             
Hit:12 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                                   
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                  
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                       
Get:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease [9 383 B]                                                                                  
Hit:15 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40,7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [104 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [600 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4 676 B]                                                                            
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4 564 B]                                                                        
Err:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                                                
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6A030B21BA07F4FB Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                           
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6A030B21BA07F4FB Google Cloud Packages Automatic Signing Key <gc-team@google.com> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
E: The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer that helped me:

Just write:

sudo su

Login as root and after that:

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

Comment: <3 u man! thx! :-)

Comment: This no longer works. Also tried the new non apt-get way. Unclear how to find *what* gpg key source even.